# Custom options not saved in `sales_flat_quote_item_option` while adding product into cart

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, sales

I have few products without custom options. This custom options plays main role in our back end process.

In the `sales_flat_order_item` table `product_options` field `product_options` is the proper field as serialized value.

But in `sales_flat_quote_item_option` table the custom field value should have been saved. In my store, most of the products are getting stored properly.

**Only few products custom options values are not saving. Anyone facing this issue?**

When I google this issue, got suggestion as PHP ini setting for `max_input_vars` should be raised. **in my case it is 2000**. So this wouldn't be the factor? Can some one advise.